# Error with R code for repeating rows in data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame called "Temperature" that is something like this:

```
Temperatures

97

98

96

98

97

V

97

98
```

And goes on like this for 48 rows. I want to repeat each row 9 times, so the data frame starts with 97 (9x) then 98 (9x) and so on. I've tried this code to do so:

```
RepeatTemp <- "Temperature"[rep(1:48(48(Temperature)), each=9]
```

Every time I run this code I get "Error: attempt to apply non-function."

How do I change this code in order to make it work?

Comment: You really need to learn how to properly use the `[` and `(` brackets in R and how to call a function. A function is called with `(`, for instance: `funName(arg1, arg2, ....)`. The square bracket is used to subset an object. For instance: `x<-1:10; x[3:5]`.

Comment: As per your request, if `df` is your `data.frame` (assuming you have one; you didn't specify which kind of object you are dealing with) and `Temperature` is the name of the column, you might try `rep(df$Temperature, each=9)`.

Comment: `48(` is not a function in R. There is an infix function named `*`. There is no adjacency assumption for multiplication. You need to look at `?Ops`. There's also no data-object named `"Temperature"`. If it exists it's named `Temperature`. Those are different expression in R.